# Updating the coworkers in nodejs

Tags: node.js, process, performance-testing

Am trying to update the changes in one worker with other worker process. It seems its taking more time to update the co-workers. With apache benchmark am getting just 500 req/sec

```
try {
  process.send({cmd:"sync_cache",objcache: objcache});
}
catch (e) {
    // 
}
```

And in master processes am updating the other workers

```
function master() {

Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach(function (id) {
    cluster.workers[id].on('message', function (msg) {
        if (msg.cmd == 'sync_cache') Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach(function (id2) {
            if (id != id2) cluster.workers[id2].process.send({cmd: 'update_cache', objcache: msg.objcache});
        });
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Is your question: why it is slower ?

Comment: yes, sometimes am getting 2000-3000 req, but am unable to figure out when and why it is dropping down to 500 req